# What does "autocorrelation/heteroscedasticity of the errors" mean?

Tags: autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, definition, clustered-standard-errors

When learning clustering error, from [this discussion](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/36215/33142)

> In general, you should look to cluster-adjust standard errors at the
> level in which you believe there exists
> autocorrelation/heteroscedasticity of the errors if you don't wish to
> (or can't) explicitly model the structural correlations within the
> regression variance-covariance matrix.

I do not fully understand what does "autocorrelation/heteroscedasticity of the errors" mean and why we need to cluster because of that.

Comment: Do [some of this posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=autocorre*+heteros*+regres*+answers%3A1) answer your Q?

Comment: you mean the hypothesis of normality of residuals ?